# how to create a message buffer in nested model case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having 4 models

- student(has_many :inboxes)
- university(has_many :inboxes)
- inbox(has_many :replies,belongs_to :student,belongs_to :university)
- reply(belons_to :inbox)

In this case i want that if a student delete something from inbox/reply ,it should remain as it is in university side.

I am not getting what concept should i use in it.

I will be highly thankful fo the help..

Comment: Add a field `is_deleted` and display only not deleted ones on the students side.

Comment: I am not getting what you r trying to consult...

Answer (score 0):

```
student.inboxes.delete(inbox)
```

This code will set the `student_id` of the `inbox` object to `nil`, so the student will not see it anymore in his list, but it won't remove the object from the university list (unless you use a `:dependent => :destroy` in your association).

Comment: @BarunSharma for the replies, you need to use a flag as suggested by fdomig